# processing for android: AssetManager and list() not working

Tags: java, android, processing

I've been developing for android using processing but have come to a halt when I wanted to retrieve a list of files within a given directory. Below is a screenshot of the code I have been trying.

[image]

I have tried different variations of this (such as getbaseContext().getAssets();) and nothing seems to work. Whenever the code tries to execute the list() part it has an error and there is nothing in 'fileNames'.

Am I missing anything? Is this a problem with processing?

Thanks

EDIT: The direction I am trying to access is "assets/Levels/" which I can see from my project view in eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it to work!
Turns out it was a problem with where I was placing the 'String[] fileNames;' code before trying to put data into it. The below code works fine:

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I experienced a similar issue because I used folder names with a trailing / character.

So for others experiencing this issue, you need to make sure the folder name you use are just the folder name with no trailing / (so "movies" instead of "movies/")

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any additional permissions in order to run the code that you have. I just compiled it on my device and it works fine. You mention you are attempting to list the files in a given directory. What you are doing is listing the files in the Levels folder, which should be a sub folder of assets. What you will get back is an array of all file names in that folder.

If you are actually looking to get a list of files from a given directory, it has nothing to do with the assets folder and I suggest you check out a tutorial on Android external and internal storage. The information directly on the android page was very helpful to me.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

If that's not what you are looking for though, I suggest rewording your question.

Comment: I'm trying to get the names of the files withing my assets/Levels/ folder that can be seen in my project view within eclipse. I'll edit my question to add this information

Comment: @JosephLittle In eclipse, under your project directory, are you sure there is a Folder called Levels, and in that folder there are various files? I ran it with 2 files and that setup, and I found both, with no permissions added.

Comment: @JosephLittle it looks solid to me, where are you checking that fileNames is null? Is there something that might be happening in another piece of code?

Comment: Oh, I've got it to work. I think it was a problem with where I was initially creating the 'fileNames' array. I'll post my solution

Answer (score 0):

**Note : Individual folder should not empty.. It will return zero for folder with no files. **

```
void getFolderDetais(String folder_name)
    {

        // pass folder_name empty to get detail of root that means assets folder details
        String[] filelistInSubfolder = assetManager.list(folder_name);
        Log.v("Floder Details ----- >", " Length --- "
                + filelistInSubfolder.length);
    }
```